# Pro [ida] == [ida-pro]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) (235 questions) and [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro) (54 questions) seem to be about the same thing.

IDA tag summary:

> The Interactive Disassembler, more commonly known as simply IDA, is a disassembler for computer software which generates assembly language source code from machine-executable code.

IDA Pro summary (no tag wiki):

> The Interactive Disassembler, more commonly known as simply IDA, is a disassembler for computer software which generates assembly language source code from machine-executable code.

AFAIK, the only difference between IDA and IDA Pro is: the normal version is free but older while the pro version is commercial and newer. Comparing the feature set they are equivalent (when comparing the same version), so distinguishing between them does not really add value.

Defining a synonym will be hard due to the few people who could vote on it. So I suggest we just retag the "pro" version and retag to [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) or a moderator could define the synonym.

Comment: That summary looks suspiciously like ones strewn about the web, and  probably came from Wikipedia originally. Anyone want to fix that while this is up?

Comment: +1, I came to Meta.SO to make the same merge request :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+13/0 in 3 months isn't much, but still a clear vote. Let's retag.

Ideally you have 2000+ reputation, so that the edit review queue does not get flodded. Remember to improve the post (spelling, formatting) when at it. And there's no real need to hurry.

Comment: It looks like you have enough rep to suggest a tag synonym now. :)

Comment: @user1354557: sorry, I still can't because I need 5 upvotes in that tag, which I don't have. Funny site.

Comment: Can't suggest tag synonym, but can suggest whole edit of said tag info. Funny site indeed.