# Clarification: Score required to suggest or vote for tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

The [Create Tag Synonyms Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) page explains how voting for tag synonyms works:

> Users with this privilege and a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. **Users with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms.**

The page repeatedly refers to "the tag" but there are actually two tags involved in a synonym request, and it is unclear which one is meant.  I believe this should be reworded to be more clear.

---

To take an example of what is unclear, let's [hypothetically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308568/pro-ida-ida-pro) say that there are two synonymous tags: [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) and [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro), and that the latter is a synonym for the former (that is, each [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro) tag should ideally become an [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) tag).

1. If I have a score of 5+ for [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) but not for [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro), can I vote for the synonym request?
2. If I have a score of 5+ for [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro) but not for [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida), can I vote for the synonym request?
3. Can I vote twice if I have a score of 5+ for both [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) and [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro)?
4. Would a 2500+ rep user need a score of 5+ on [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) or [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro) (or both) to suggest the tag synonym?

(As it turns out, I know the answer to #1 because I've already voted, but the others are still unclear)

---

**Should we improve the clarity of this page?  If so, how?**

Comment: I vote we should improve the clarity and usefulness of the entire system by [allowing anyone who meets an arbitrary rep threshold to suggest a tag synonym, regardless of score in that tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag).

Comment: Wow, the number of feature requests around the synonym system, just web-walking the "Related" lists and cross-reference comments, is staggering. Some date back 5 or more years, right back to the introduction of the feature. Apparently one dev decided to [deliberately make voting difficult](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58852/237313), but the majority of the FRs aren't status-declined, just quietly gathering dust. What will it take to decide that the whole system is long overdue a review?

Comment: The effective reality is, you can't vote for tag synonyms, with a few exceptions that are so rare that you might as well ignore them. If you need a synonym set up, post on meta, and cross your fingers that a helpful admin-type person will see it.

Comment: @Martha Might as well ditch the whole voting system and just transfer it all over to meta. The system that's in place now has little value as it is right now.

Comment: The Meta system is also badly broken. What you get are a bunch of vigilantes who see your question and decide to act on it immediately, going through and massively retagging a bunch of questions. Putting aside the issue of rep gain with people who suggest edits, even when trusted users do it, it's massively disruptive because it relaunches all of those old, already-answered questions back onto the home page for everyone to accidentally click on again. The synonym system is *way* better because it is non-disruptive.

Comment: Could someone offer answers to the four questions regarding score requirements?

Answer (score 3):

**1. If I have a score of 5+ for [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) but not for [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro), can I vote for the synonym request?**

You can vote to make [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) a synonym of [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro), but not vice versa

**2. If I have a score of 5+ for [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro) but not for [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida), can I vote for the synonym request?**

You can vote to make [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro) a synonym of [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida), but not vice versa

**3. Can I vote twice if I have a score of 5+ for both [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) and [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro)?**

As [confirmed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327539/clarification-score-required-to-suggest-or-vote-for-tag-synonyms/400029#comment787713_400029) by TheMaster, the reverse synonym cannot be suggested in the first place, therefore you cannot double-vote.

**Would a 2500+ rep user need a score of 5+ on [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) or [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro) (or both) to suggest the tag synonym?**

Yes, suggesting a synonym *requires* you to have 5+ score on a tag:

- If you have 5+ score on [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida), but not on [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro), you are eligible.
- If you do not have 5+ score on [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida), but have on [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro), you are out of luck.
- If you have 5+ score on [ida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida) and 5+ score on [ida-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ida-pro) - good for you!

---

Side note: if you *suggest* the tag synonym, you will not be able to vote for it.

---

To illustrate what happens in each situation, here are some screenshots and sample cases:

1. Voting with score < 5 on the tag *to which* a synonym is added:

[image: score ltn 5 on voting screenshot]

2. Suggesting a synonym *for* the tag with score < 5:

[image: score ltn 5 on suggesting screenshot]

3. Suggesting a tag as a synonym if it is already a synonym:

[image: suggesting a synonym that is a synonym]

Comment: Vote twice for what?

Comment: @TheMaster - I don't know, that's the problem - these are the OP's questions, I suspect the flow is something like this: A suggests to synonymize 1 to 2, B suggests to synonymize 2 to 1 (if that is even possible) -> the question is whether the OP will be able to upovte/downvote both of them

Comment: B cannot suggest as long as there is  a pending synonym request on A

Comment: @TheMaster - thank you, then we have all 4 questions answered :) I can make it a CW if you'd like and you / me can fill in the last blank

Comment: No.  You can fill it up:)

Comment: @TheMaster - ok then, thank you, I will add as soon as I can (I want to add a couple of error screenshots as well)